# How to create a Hash Sha-256 where the first 3 characters of the hash are zeros?

Tags: python, hash

I want to create a hash Sha-256 where the first 3 characters of the hash are zeros.

I'm doing this code on `Python`:

```py
import hashlib

hashsha = hashlib.sha256()
n=input(10)
hashsha.update(n.encode())
print (hashsha.hexdigest())
```

The ouput is

> 2c624232cdd221771294dfbb310aca000a0df6ac8b66b696d90ef06fdefb64a3

But what I want the hash this way

> 00024232cdd221771294dfbb310aca000a0df6ac8b66b696d90ef06fdefb64a3.

I did some research and I don't find anything.

Comment: `b'number_16948391'` produces `sha256` with six zeroes. This is easier than I've anticipated: `000000ab2d8a384d72ee91a0792fdf78377ccc2967b387f346a9fa070ad90e06`

Answer (score 0):

You should basically keep trying... It is not easy to find hash collisions, even for a few digits.

This code will find you a few:

```
import hashlib

hashsha = hashlib.sha256()

for n in range(1000000):
    hashsha.update(str(n).encode())
    h = hashsha.hexdigest()
    if h.startswith("000"):
        print(f'String: "{n}" Hash: {h}')
```

Output:

```
String: "2629" Hash: 0007d4960f1c22f3e8ba3f7f4e927de97383ea3ca5bf3d86342e149f693a65c3
String: "4316" Hash: 000c5df2f4ee5da1eadafa896a5f2a92cdf01a712a95ae56776986e353bb6e2b
String: "6073" Hash: 00020de5ef9d424991c213955e1b21b63cf25740a6e1a9d7e14f76dcd6f12022
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(10000):
    string = f"number_{i}".encode()
    hashsha = hashlib.sha256(string).hexdigest()
    if '000' == hashsha[:3]:
        print(string)
```

So here's one number:

```
hashlib.sha256(b'number_4283').hexdigest()
```

Output is:
`000a16ff44e6501bb2c4f72e8fa51c5b0acbfb87bfa85b05e512a05b78726623`